# En un reporte no me muestra los mismos datos en la vista original que en el diseño de impresión

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Resulta que a la hora de mostrar un informe con una tabla, la tabla muestra como 30 items en la vista original, sin embargo cuando eligo que me muestre el informe como diseño de impresión me muestra la misma tabla pero con varias filas menos. Mi pregunta es, porque me muestra la tabla con menos filas.

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

[image: Modo normal]

[image: Diseño de impresión]

Comment: ASi como esta la pregunta, deberiamos adivinar respuestas... podrias tratar de aclarar todo?

Comment: Resulta que tengo un informe con una tabla en el cuerpo del reporte, a la hora de mostrar el informe me lo muestra bien con 253 páginas, hasta ahí todo correcto, pero a la hora de darle al botón de vista previa de impresión me aparecen 325 páginas y he visto que la tabla no me muestra todos los artículos que se pintan cuando se compone el informe. Para tratar de aclararlo voy a poner capturas del informe de una manera y de otra:

Comment: Has etiquetado con C# la pregunta, pero no hay una sóla línea de código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La vista de impresión muchas veces es diferente a la vista original, lo preocupante es cuando en una página te muestra un grupo de columnas y en la otra el resto de las columnas que faltaron, si te pasa eso entonces debes modificar los bordes del reporte, yo siempre pongo estos bordes en 0, hay 4 tipos de borde izquierda, derecha, arriba y abajo. A las propiedades del reporte se accede dando clic en el icono que tiene forma de llave, arriba en la barra de herramientas del visualstudio, donde mismo están los botoncitos de salvar pero a la derecha. Otra cosa en la que debes fijarte es en sí tienes muchas columnas, por defecto el reportviewer te marca la opción portrait ojo de ser tu caso debes marcar landscape y así quedará invertido la hoja del reporte permitiéndote mostrar más columnas, no parece que este sea tu caso pero igual te lo explico, fíjate también en la propiedad paper size por defecto te pone A4, eso depende del papel que vas a usar para imprimir, el más común es letter o carta que es el que yo uso porque imprimo con ese tipo de papel